# How to override symfony password check to be able to check against multiple types of hashes

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have an old database of users which contains passwords hashed in a way I don't like.
I'd like for those hashes to be updated to a new hash form (bcrypt) when they log in.

I am using FOSUserBundle to manage users and [Elnur's bcrypt bundle](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle) as security encoder. Is there an easy way to plug into the password check mechanism to add this kind of algorithm:

```
if passwordHash is using old format
  oldFormatHash := hash userGivenPassword in the old way
  if oldFormatHash == passwordHash
     login ok
     update password in database with new hash format
  else
     login ko
else
  use default
```

I thought about extending the current security encoder but the `isPasswordValid` method does not have the id of the account to check (or its canonical name) so the updating part is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it can help someone faced with this problem, here is the solution I used.
The old way of storing the passwords in the database did not use salts. So I updated this column to contain the user's id.

Then it was easy to create my own security encoder using the salt parameter to update the user's password hashes.